# Excel cannot complete this task, insufficient memory, insufficient resources

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I try to copy-paste from an excel file to another one I get this error :

> Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other apps.

My documents are in the network drive not on my local. I have tried all the solution I found in the internet but the error persists.

[image]

Comment: Maybe adding more context would help, like if you can say if the copy and paste work in the past (with the same amount of data being copied and pasted)?.

Comment: Is your processor 32-bit?

Comment: It's a 64-bit processor

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this can happen. Does your Excel have a lot of data, using VBA, complex pivot tables, icons, lots of shapes? Do you use Ctrl+A replication? My suggestion is that you can

1. try disabling add-ins, disabling macros
2. Remove redundant shapes and simplify your charts
3. Use right-click copy instead of shortcut keys to copy (this will increase the size of copied files, data)

Comment: My excel document have 1529 ko with 15 worksheets, the error keeps apprearing when i try to copy the content of one sheet (9579 cells that are not blank) to another excel document

Comment: Does this happen when trying to copy fewer cells, such as ten rows of cells?

Comment: Yes, it happens even when i copy just a few number of cells (5 rows of cells)